# Where to find nameservers obtained from DHCP (via NetworkManager)?

Tags: dns, networkmanager, dhcp

To learn, I am writing my own caching DNS server (à la dnsmasq, but in Python instead). From DHCP, NetworkManager obtains upstream nameservers and places them in `/etc/resolv.conf`. My system also looks in `/etc/resolv.conf` to find nameservers to query.

I need to place my own DNS server (`127.0.0.1`) in `/etc/resolv.conf` so my system will query it, but NetworkManager will overwrite the file. If I disallow/configure NetworkManager not to overwrite `/etc/resolv.conf`, my DNS server will not be able to find caching nameservers because NetworkManager doesn't write them there.

It seems that `/etc/resolv.conf` symlinks to `/var/run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf`, so I guess I could have my DNS server find upstream servers there? I'd just `chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf` to prevent NetworkManager from overwriting it. Is this how I'm supposed to do it, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

chattr will work. It tells NM to leave resolv.conf alone. Alternatively, see`rc-manager` in `man NetworkManager.conf`.

NM will always write to it's internal resolv.conf in var/run, so you could scrape that.
Or you use `nmcli -f all device show`, or use a dispatcher script (`man NetworkManager`).

Finally, you could write your own DNS plugin. But that requires you to rebuild NM from source, and the plugin API is not public/stable either.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning so many good options! Reading about `rc-manager` in `man networkmanager.conf`, I see it will always write to the runtime directory regardless of what it does with `/etc`. That's exactly what I needed and the easiest option. I didn't think of trying to get it from nmcli, and I didn't know NM has dispatcher scripts. And that explains how dnsmasq does it, since NM has a specific dnsmasq setting (i.e. must be a plugin). Thanks again!